# Split view using docusaurus

Tags: documentation, docusaurus

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

[example image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYbjI.png)

Is there a way to do this using docusaurus?

Answer (score 0):

As Docusaurus uses [Infima](https://facebookincubator.github.io/infima/) (a facebook styling framework), that should be possible using maybe a custom module and the [Grid](https://facebookincubator.github.io/infima/docs/layout/grid) for layouting it accordingly? just an idea, not a complete solution.